# Modal Box not opening

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open a modal box on clicking a button using twitter bootstrap 3.0 . However on clicking the button there is no modal box shows up.

```
<tr>
   <td height=150>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Anonymous Question</button>
   </td>  
</tr>   

// the modal code
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal End -->
```

Comment: have you checked your console for any js error? is everything else (bootstrap) working properly?

Comment: Why are you using `href`? Use `data-target="#myModal"` with `<button>`s

Comment: Works for me if you use `data-target`: http://jsfiddle.net/8gs6L/ (I didn't bother trying with `href`)

Comment: Make sure your bootstrap script is being included - remember that it needs to be included after jQuery.

Comment: data-target="#myModal" worked. 
thanks